# CherryPy Real-Time Web Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, cherrypy

I've inherited a web application that is running a CherryPy web server. I need to implement a user interface that will automatically update with data from the server. Right now the solution is to use JavaScript polling. While it works, it feels dirty.

I would love to use Socket.IO, but I cannot find any support for doing this with a CherryPy backend. Does any one have any insight into this approach?

WebSockets would be great too, except for the need to support IE. Are there any non-Flash fallbacks for IE? And as for WebSocket support in CherryPy I have found ws4py, but I don't know have any experience using it.

Are there any Comet implementations for CherryPy.

For what it's worth I have been scouring the internet the last few days looking for solutions, but I really haven't found any "this is exactly what you can do" results.

Is it possible and does it make any sense to install Node.JS and have the client UI communicate with the Node.JS server which that talks to CherryPy? Or is that just wasteful?

Thanks!